# How to adb pull folders and adb creates correct folder name?

Tags: android, shell, adb

i want to `adb pull sdcard/` everything including folders and the content. what else do i have to add so that adb auto creates the folder names?

E.g

Sdcard: folder1, folder2, folder3

after adb pull

i want folder1, folder2, folder3 on my hdd.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a directory to "adb pull", it automatically copies the folders to your local drive in their original hierarchy.  Note that you must pass the full path, e.g.

```
adb pull /sdcard/
```

(note the leading slash)

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this here because I think it can help somebody else.
Not only the leading slash is important, but also the trailing one, and you get the same error with:

```
adb pull /sdcard
```

This is the (only?) correct syntax:

```
adb pull /sdcard/
```

In theory they would be equivalent, accordingly to the UNIX syntax, but they are not, at least for ADB.